# How can I create a nokogiri case insensitive text * search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, case-sensitive

Currnetly I am doing

```
words = []
words << "philip morris"
words << "Philip morris"
words << "philip Morris"
words << "Philip Morris"
for word in words
  doc.search("[text()*='#{word}']")
end
```

When I was using hpricot I found where to downcase the results within the gem so I could just keep all my searchs lowercase, however nokogiri has been quite difficult to find where one could even do that. Is anyone aware of a way to do this?
Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lower-case` XPath function is not available but you can use the `translate` XPath 1.0 function to convert your text to lowercase e.g. for the English alphabet:

```
translate(text(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

I couldn't seem to use this in combination with the `*=` operator but you can use `contains` to do a substring search instead, making the full thing:

```
doc.search("//*[contains(translate(text(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'philip morris')]")
```